# How to convert LINQ query to work with EF Core

Tags: linq, ef-core-3.1

I'm converting from EF6 to EF Core 3.1 and this LINQ query is failing with a runtime exception stating 'The LINQ expression ... could not be translated.

The group by is what is causing the issue, but I'm not sure how to rewrite it to work with EF Core and keep the result in a nested list.

```
Notification notification = new Notification()
{
   ProductReminders = new List<List<ProductNotification>>(),
   ProductStats = new List<StatResult>()
};

var profileCode = 123;
notification.ProductReminders = 
   (from ng in ProductNotification
    where ng.UserProfileCode == profileCode
    orderby ng.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
    group ng by ng.GroupGUID into groupG
    select (from pn in ProductNotification
            join p in Product on pn.ProductID equals p.ProductID
            where pn.UserProfileCode == profileCode
            && pn.GroupGUID == groupG.Key
            orderby pn.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
            select new ProductNotification()
            {
               ProductDetail = new ProductDetail()
               {
                  ProductId = pn.ProductID ?? 0,
                  Upc = p.UPC,
                  Brand = p.Description,
                  Manufacturer = p.Name,
                  ProfileCode = p.ProfileCode,
               },
               EndDate = pn.EndDate,
               NotificationId = pn.NotificationID,
               Status = pn.Status,
               GroupGuid = pn.GroupGUID
            })
            .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since grouping operator has limitations, I would suggest to read all needed data and provide grouping on the client side. Query in your case will be much effective:

```cs
// select only needed data from database
var minimalRequiredData = 
    from pn in ProductNotification
    join p in Product on pn.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    where pn.UserProfileCode == profileCode
    select new ProductNotification
    {
        ProductDetail = new ProductDetail
        {
            ProductId = pn.ProductID ?? 0,
            Upc = p.UPC,
            Brand = p.Description,
            Manufacturer = p.Name,
            ProfileCode = p.ProfileCode,
        },
        EndDate = pn.EndDate,
        NotificationId = pn.NotificationID,
        Status = pn.Status,
        GroupGuid = pn.GroupGUID
    };

// materialize result
var materialized = minimalRequiredData.ToList();

// form required result shape using IEnumerable<T>
var resultQuery = 
    from m in materialized
    orderby ng.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
    group m by new m.GroupGUID into g
    select g.Orderby(x => x.EndDate ?? ng.EndDate).ToList();

notification.ProductReminders = resultQuery.ToList();
```